# (iOS+Flutter) Camera working properly when doing testing, but black screen when testing the version from firebase app distribution

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, photoview

I'm currently working on a flutter project that use camera plugin. when I tested it during development and on my local devices, it is working. the camera snap a photo and display the image on the screen.

However after I compiled it and upload it into firebase app distribution, it just shows a black screen after I snap a photo. I did not have the same issue in android. to be sure I upload again the latest code and re build a new app and upload it into the app distribution, but still the same issue exist. [image]

these are the current setting:

flutter: 3.3.10
photo_view: 0.14.0
camera: 0.10.3+2